# How to connect to a Clipper (E5) DBF File (with an SMT) using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb, dbf, clipper

I am trying to connect to a DBF (`HISTORY.DBF`) that has a linked SMT file (`HISTORY.SMT`). I have multiple DBF files and I can connect to all of them except the ones with SMT files.

Looking at the header information of the DBFs suggests it is a Clipper (E5 Header) format DBF which reads fine using the connection code below for most files, but once I try to read a file with an associated SMT it fails with the fault:

> External table is not in the expected format

My Code is as below

```
Dim dsDataSet As New DataSet
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim daDataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Dim strFilePath As String = gloStrPath & "data"
Dim strDBF As String = "HISTORY.DBF"

Try
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";Extended Properties=dBase III;"
    dBaseConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    If dBaseConnection.State = 0 Then dBaseConnection.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, 16, "Error")
End Try

Try
    daDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " & strDBF, dBaseConnection)
    daDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSet, "Name")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, 16, "Error")
End Try
```

Can anyone offer any insight into what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: I have done some more messing around and found that if I change the header information from e5 to 03 (Clipper to dBase III) then I can load the data fine using vb.net.  it means making a copy of the DBF and editing the first byte, but it gets me where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

These files appear to be DBFs that were created with the HiPer-Six format with SMT memo files.  Check this https://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html